# Is it possible to convert code into a logical graph?

Tags: algorithm, logic

Is it possible to convert code into a logical graph?

---

#### EDIT:

What I am thinking is that math is absolute. We can judge whether it is right or wrong for sure. But for code, there is something other than the logic. What I want to do is remove that 'something' to keep the logic there only.

Comment: yup,I can't possibly think of an algorithm to implement this kind of thing,do you have any ideas?

Comment: Hard to give,though.
You get it if ever thought of.

Comment: do you want a graph ( a mathematical object consisting of a set of nodes and a set of pairs of nodes ), or a picture of a graph?

Comment: This question does not make much sense. Firstly, it is not at all true that in mathematics it's always possible to judge if something is true or not (this fundamental discovery is attributed to Kurt Gödel). Also what exactly is this 'something other than logic' that programs have, that you wish to get rid of? Can you be more precise about what you are after?

Answer (score 2):

it's possible. flowcharts are logical graphs and could easily be generated by a computer. Every code structure has a corresponding [flowchart structure](http://users.evtek.fi/~jaanah/IntroC/DBeech/3gl_flow.htm).

quick google brought up: [Code Visual to Flowchart](http://www.fatesoft.com/s2f/)

---

as far as inverse, flowcharts are much too broad to convert to code.
There are graphical programming languages though. for instance [NI's labView fpga](http://www.ni.com/fpga/) is all graphical programming which can then be converted into VHDL.

Comment: But it seems this kind of flowchart not so helpful to identify the problem,you think?

Comment: And is it possible to do the inverse?

Comment: well, flow charts were meant to be made to plan a task so you know the logic before implementation. but I think looking at directed graphs could help iron out certain problems in the code.

although they are meant to be on a much higher level than code so looking at code via graphs could get pretty messy.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is exactly what you mean, but static analysers like clang parse code, determine all possible branches the code could take, and check for errors. For example, given the code..

```
1. if(somefunction()){
2.    this_will_break();
3. } else {
4.     if(anotherfunction()){
5.         printf("%i", str(something));
6.     }
7.     print("this is fine");
8. }
```

You will get output along the lines:

```
Line 1. Taking true branch.
Line 1. Error: Function this_will_break is not defined
Line 4. Taking true branch.
Line 5. Warning: Function passed incompatible type
```

You could potentially graph these paths, but I don't see why you would want to (it wouldn't really show anything)

Another possibly similar idea is [Gprof2Dot](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot), which takes profiling data, and draws a hierarchal Graphviz chart showing how long each function takes to run, which function called it and so on.

A final thing springs to mind, which is nodal based applications like [Shake](http://www.apple.com/shake/), or [Quartz Composer](http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/quartz/quartzcomposer.html) - ways of "programming visually", representing code like `Add(Blur(MyImage), Blur(AlphaChannel))` as:

```
[MyImage]--->[Blur]----\/
                      [Add]
                       /\
[AlphaChannel]----------
```

Those aren't logical graphs, but they are ways of visually representing code, which might possibly give you some ideas.. maybe.. unless I'm totally misunderstanding..

Comment: it's close.
What I'm thinking is that:
Math is absolute,say,we can judge it's right or wrong for quite sure.
But for the code,there is something over the logic.
What I want to do is remove that 'something' to keep the logic there only.

Answer (score 0):

At least the inverse is possible. When programming Siemen's PLCs one of the more common programming forms is "Ladder Logic", where you program graphically.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_logic

Comment: What about other languages like php,python and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Or like reverse engineered UML, with class and sequence diagrams?

Not as valuable as the code itself, IMO.  Once you reach a meaningful degree of complexity it's impossible to take in an entire diagram or graph.  And the problems that can be graphed effectively aren't worth the effort.

No debuggers or unit tests for graphical representations of any kind.

The value of pictures and design is to reach a point where you understand the problem well enough to code.  But once you reach that point, I'd argue that the marginal utility of making them equivalent to engineering drawings isn't worth the effort.

Comment: What I wish is to make the coding process more logic,though.

Comment: Graphing won't simplify inherent complexity.  The only way to do that is with decomposition, both in code and diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

This merely serves the inverse of what you want but [csgraph.com](https://www.csgraph.com) allows you to draw graphs and generate their code form in either Adj List or Adj Matrix format.

[Screenshot of Webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAVLH.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As you actually stated in your answer, this doesn't answer the question so probably shouldn't be left as one. I would recommend taking a look at [answer] for information on how to answer questions. From review.